# How should I keep consistency?Laravel. I would like to insert data about user when a new user is generated

Tags: php, laravel

How should I keep consistency?
I would like to do "insert" to another table when a new user is registered.

tables
user
//data equals request that validated.

```
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'profile' => $data['profile'],
            'adress' => $data['adress']
```

additional_table
worker_id has a foreign key of the user_id.

```
'worker_id' =>  $user->id,  
'place' => $request->place
```

Laravel Auth register.

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        if($request->user_type == 1)
        {
            DB::table('additional')->updateOrInsert(
                ['worker_id' =>  $user->id,  
                ['place' => $request->place)]
            );
        }
        $this->guard()->login($user);

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 201)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Comment: first do select and check, if not then insert..

Comment: Does something not work? `['worker_id' =>  $user->id,  ['place' => $request->place)]` looks like it has too many brackets

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might work:

```
DB::table('additional')->insertOrIgnore([
    ['worker_id' => $user->id, 'place' => $request->place]
]);
```